# Facebook share thumbnail for a website

Tags: html, facebook, thumbnails

I have used all the meta tag in rails app for facebook sharing and tested it facebook debugger. It is taking image not from `og-image` tag . It is taking image from an ad which is posted on my site. But should it not take image from from the content i set in `og-image` ?

I added prefix tag , and image url is also correct. I also set image type just for trial. But it is not working.

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<meta property="og:image" content="domain/images/facebook-share-image.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg"> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630"> </head>
```

If you need other info regarding this, I am ready to serve.
Thank You.

Comment: how does your html look like? (header-part)

Comment: `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<meta property="og:image" content="domain/images/facebook-share-image.jpg"/>
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
</head>`

Comment: Please edit that in your question. Forgive me, I need the first first row including html and body tags to.

Comment: Did you try using the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)? It should tell you what issues you may have.

Comment: Yes I tried it. It is not taking the image. It takes image from ad. As I said before.

Comment: html tag is not different. I have not added any changes there.

Comment: go to  [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) paste your web address and click **Fetch New Scrap Information**

Comment: I have already tried it bro.

Comment: You need to use an absolute URL for `og:image`.

Comment: yes bro, I used absolute url in domain